# Replace a variable with text (sed)

Tags: bash, sed

I have to find a specific text in the file and then replace that text with some new text.

The contents of the file are:

```
host=100
servers=4
clients=70
```

I have tried this:

```
var=$(grep "servers=" /path/to/file)
sed -i "s/${var}/servers=5/g" /path/to/file
```

But it gives me the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
```

Note: All I want is to update the value of each of the variable i.e. servers=4 should be replaced by servers=5.

Please help me figure out the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want the `var`? Why don't you write it directly in `sed`?

Comment: try to add `echo $var ` right after `var=` line ti see what you've got over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `grep` ends with a newline character. `sed` expects the whole command on one line or escaping line breaks.

However, you can easily achieve the complete task with `sed` only:

```
sed -i 's/^servers=[0-9]*$/servers=5/' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i.bak "s/servers=[0-9]*/servers=5/" /path/to/file
```